# Filter NSArray of custom objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, filtering

I have a `NSArray` of `Contact` objects, we can call it `contacts`. Contact is a superclass, `FacebookGroup` and `Individual` are subclasses of `Contact`. `FacebookGroup` has a property  called `individuals` which is a set of `Individual` objects.

I also have a `NSArray` of `NSString` objects, we can call it `userIDs`.

What I want to do is create a new `NSArray` from the existing `contacts` array that match the userIDs in `userIDs`.

So if `contacts` has 3 `Contact` objects with `userID` 1,2 and 3. And my `userIDs` has a `NSString` object 3. Then I want the resulting array to contain `Contact` which equals `userID` 3.

**Contact.h**

```
Contact : NSObject
```

**FacebookGroup.h**

```
FacebookGroup : Contact

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *individuals;
```

**Individual.h**

```
Individual : Contact

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID IN %@", userIDs];
NSArray *filtered = [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add some information. The `Contact` object is actually a superclass which doesn't have the `userID` property. The subclasses `FacebookGroup` and `Individual` have the `userID` property. See my updated question.

Comment: @PeterWarbo: OK, but I think that the code should work for that case as well, did you try it?

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting information. `FacebookGroup` does not have a property `userID` instead it has a property for a `NSSet` of `Individual` objects. I updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userId = %@", myContact.userId];
NSArray *filteredArray = [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add some information. The `Contact` object is actually a superclass which doesn't have the `userID` property. The subclasses `FacebookGroup` and `Individual` have the `userID` property. See my updated question.

Answer (score -1):

i'm expecting you want like this once see this one,

```
 NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil];
    NSMutableArray *ids = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"2", @"3", nil];
    NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<[ids count];i++){
       if([[ids objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"2"])
           [array addObject:[names objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

O/P:-

```
(
    two,
    three
)
```